# request.user returning abstract user (django-stubs)

Tags: python, django, typing, django-stubs

I am trying to type the following:

```
user: Final[CustomUser] = self.request.user
```

Where `CustomUser` is my custom user model defined in `settings.py`. My IDE complains that `Expected type 'CustomUser', got 'AbstractBaseUser' instead`. Looking at the documentation, it says that `self.request.user` returns an instance of `AUTH_USER_MODEL` however clearly this is not happening.

Also tried:

```
 def get(self, request: MyRequest, *args, **kwargs) -> HttpResponse:
    user: Final[CustomUser] = self.request.user
```

Where

```
from django.http import HttpRequest
from my_user_app.models import CustomUser

class MyRequest(HttpRequest):
    user: CustomUser
```

Comment: `request.user` returns an `AnonymousUser` for users that are not logged in. Does your `CustomUser` model subclass from `AbstractBaseUser`?

Comment: @IainShelvington It extends `AbstractUser`. Is that not enough ?

Comment: Which IDE/plugin/framework are you using? I don't think Django has type annotations

Comment: @IainShelvington PyCharm and django-stubs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an open issue regarding this error here https://github.com/typeddjango/django-stubs/issues/309

According to the docs for django-stubs you have to provide your own request type when using a custom user model. At the bottom of the page on PyPi [How can I use HttpRequest with custom user model?](https://pypi.org/project/django-stubs/)

```
from django.http import HttpRequest
from my_user_app.models import CustomUser

class MyRequest(HttpRequest):
    user: CustomUser
```

Then you would have to use this to annotate `self.request`

```
 def get(self, request: MyRequest, *args, **kwargs) -> HttpResponse:
    user: Final[CustomUser] = request.user
```

Comment: Tried this but it still complains

Comment: Can you add where you have tried this to your question?

Comment: Edited. Is this what you suggested means?

Comment: Shouldn't you use the `request` parameter passed to the method and not `self.request`?

Comment: is self.request same as just using request there ? (because the annotations work like you've suggested now) - I'm just not sure if there are adverse effects

Comment: It's not the same as the class that your method is in has a different type for `self.request` https://github.com/typeddjango/django-stubs/blob/master/django-stubs/views/generic/base.pyi

Comment: You need to either have a base view class that correctly annotates `request` or figure out how to override django-stubs

Comment: There is an open issue regarding this error here https://github.com/typeddjango/django-stubs/issues/309